# How to say "to set a timer"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to know how to say "to set a timer" as in "set a timer for 5 minutes (on your phone)".

If I search in Reta-Vortaro for "timer", it just says "nenio trovigxis".

Maybe I could say:

> "agordi tempilon por soni post 5 minutoj"

But I have no idea how to say "timer". Tempilo seems completely wrong. Also, is the rest of this sentence correct?

Comment: Krom Vikipedio kaj Reta Vortaro, vi povas serĉi en la [tradukoj de Mozilla](https://transvision.mozfr.org/) (Firefox, Common Voice). Tie ankaŭ eblas korekti/sugesti (sekvu la ligilon al *edit in Pontoon*) aŭ, ĉar vi jam trovis ke tio rilatas `temp`, iri al PIV kaj serĉi tion.

Comment: Interese! Bone, dankon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ebla traduko estas: `tempumilo`.

Jen difino de [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#tempumilo_kd):

> tempumilo Ⓣ Aparato aŭ parto de aparato, de sistemo, kiu funkcias aŭ
> ĉesas funkcii post difinita tempo

> "set a timer for 5 minutes (on your phone)"

Vi povus skribi "meti 5 minutan tempumilon", sed konsiderinda estas io kiel "meti alarmon por post 5 minutoj".

Tiu "por post + momento" signifas ke post la paso de tiu momento io okazos:

```
liaj planoj por post la liberiĝo
alarmo por post kvin minutoj
```

Comment: Interese! Jes! Mi sxatas "meti alarmon post 5 minutoj", sed kiel oni povus eviti konfuzon inter "set a timer for five minutes" (por ke gxi sonu post kvin minutoj) kaj "set a timer in five minutes" (meti alarmon post la paso de 5 minutoj)?

Comment: Vi pravas, kaj fakte ne estas konfuzo, kion mi skribis signifus nur "atendi kvin minutojn kaj poste meti alarmon". Mi anstataŭigis tion per "por poste".

Comment: Tre interese! Bonege, dankon!

Answer (score 1):

Laŭ PIV la verbo "[meti](https://vortaro.net/#meti_kd)" havas ankaŭ figurasencan difinon:

> Transigi iun, ion en difinitan staton; fari, ke iu, io estu ia

Mi komprenas la ekzemplojn en PIV tiel, ke oni metas alarmon aŭ funkcion, kiu okazu post iu periodo.

- Metu alarmon aktiviĝi/okazi (per tempumilo) post 5 minutoj.

Alternative oni povas uzi la verbon "agordi" (vd. "[agordi 4](https://vortaro.net/#agordi_kd))

- Agordu la tempumilon por alarmi/funkcii post 5 minutoj.

Kiam temas pri tiu eblo de konfuzo, miaopinie la pozicio de "post 5 minutoj" gravas.

- Metu alarmon aktiviĝi post 5 minutoj.
- Post 5 minutoj metu alarmon aktiviĝi.

Comment: +1 por _agordi_ anstataŭ _meti_. _Meti_ + objekto + infinitivo ŝajnas stranga al mi.

Comment: `Agordu la tempumilon por alarmi` ... Tio aspektas vere strange, nu, fakte malĝuste. Eble `por ke ĝi ...` aŭ simple `por alarmo`. Kial? Ĉar `por + infinitivo` dividus la subjekton kun la antaŭa frazo, sed la alarmanto kaj la agordanto ne estas samaj. Same kun `meti + objketo + infinitivo`, tio estas malĝusta, se tio entute validus (mi neniam rekontis tiun strukturon), la du agojn plu farus la sama subjekto.

Comment: Interese! Eble "agordi alarmon aktiviĝontan post 5 minutoj"?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, pardonu mian malfruan respondon. Ni havas la esprimon "Ŝi petis al Karlo razi sin", kiu havas kaŝitan subjekton, t.e. la suferanto de la verbo "peti" (esprimita per "al" en Esperanto) samtempe estas la subjekto de la verbo "razi sin". Al mi tio ŝajnas simile kiel "Agordu la tempumilon por alarmi". Aŭ ĉu vi celas, ke oni ne bezonas la prepozicion "por"? Kaj "Agoru la tempumilon alarmi" sufiĉas?

Comment: Via ekzemplo rilatas [agoinfluan ĉefverbon](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/aliaj_frazroloj/kun_alia_subjekto.html#i-7mr), tial la subjekto de la i-verbo estas alia. Sed `agordi` ne estas *agoinflua*, tial, laŭ mia lingvasento, en `meti tempumilon por alarmi` «la subjekto [estas egala al tiu de la ĉefverbo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kun_rolvortetoj.html)».

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, lasu min kontroli, ĉu mi komprenas ĝuste. Laŭ vi la problemo koncernas la subjekton de la infinitivo, ĉar tiu estas la sama kiel de la ĉefverbo. Do ĉu  substantivo, "alarmo", estas pli bona?

Comment: Jes, tiurilate mi pensas ke `alarmo` bonus, ĉar ĝi [estas la celo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/aliaj_rolvortetoj/por.html#i-5a2) de la agordado. Sed, nu, tiu estas nur mia opinio.